# deployment to heroku causes pandas to read in my csv file incorrectly for my streamlit app

Tags: pandas, csv, heroku, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that uses three datasets to give descriptive statistics about three cities. Libraries used are: Streamlit, Pandas and Numpy.
My streamlit app works perfectly on my local machine, but after deploying to heroku. Pandas doesn't read in the csv dataset correctly. It simply reads in the version, oid and size. Also i used GIT LFS to upload my datasets to github (Each dataset surpasses the 25mb limit). I followed the instructions on how to deploy an app to Heroku carefully from this video (https://youtu.be/JwSS70SZdyM?t=10526).

This image below is what pandas reads in:

[image: This is what pandas.read_csv() function reads in]

I truly don't know what to try as i haven't seen a solution to this problem on stackoverflow before.

Comment: What file format is your dataset?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I have a similar problem and no great solution so far. I disabled GitLFS as my test ‘.csv’ is small and behaviors went back to normal. I tried reading the data using multiple encodings but not luck.